# How to look for $invalid, or $error.required, $error.pattern using a simple html form and directive?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using angularJS directive and i want to find each input whether it has any errors, for example: required or pattern is incorrect.

HTML:

```
<form validation name="loginForm" ng-submit="form(this)">
     <label> example 1
          <input type="text" name="firstname" ng-model="user.firstname" ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'mousedown blur'}" required
                   ng-pattern="validationPatterns.firstname">
     </label>

     <label> example 2
            <input type="text" name="lastname" ng-model="user.lastname" ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'mousedown blur'}" required
                   ng-pattern="validationPatterns.lastname">
     </label>

     <button class="btn" type="submit">Continue</button>
</form>
```

Directive: This outputs the names of each input name ( firstname and lastname and it includes all the objects like $required, $errors, $invalid etc...)

```
element.find('button').on('click', function () {
    var input = element.find('input');

    angular.forEach(input, function (inputs) {
        var inputName = $(inputs).attr('name');
        console.log(scope.loginForm[inputName]);
    });
});
```

Now how do I check each element input, for example:

if input[name].$error.required=== true, show an error message. I wanted to check this on the directive not the HTML

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
<div class="input-group">
        <label for="firstname">Firstname</label> <input name="firstname" type="text"
            class="form-control input-sm" ng-model="user.firstname" required />
        <span
            ng-show="loginForm.firstname.$error.required && loginForm.firstname.$dirty">Required!
        </span>
</div>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Yes this does work but I wanted that to work on a directive instead.